# g++/clang ultra fast parse but not compile mode?

Tags: c++, g++, clang

Is there some ultra fast "syntax check my code, but don't compile mode" for g++/clang? Where the only goal is to just check if the code I have is valid C++ code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

-fsyntax-only for GCC, this should probably work for Clang as well since they emulate GCC's command line options.   Whether or not it's significantly faster, you'll have to time.

Comment: The speed issue is really how much time is spent on read source I/O, on syntax checking, how much time compiling, and how much time doing object output I/O. I suspect that with enough source includes read I/O may be a large portion and you'll see minimal gain from syntax checking only.

Comment: @Mark: In my experience caching the compiled output with ccache made almost always sense. And don't forget that C++ might also include templates which can make pure compile times skyrocket.

Comment: Note that in g++, this only parses the code and doesn't instantiate, so you can miss many errors. clang++ stops after instantiation, which can take a bit longer but is more useful. Also, some of the g++ warnings are produced during the code optimization phase, so you'll miss those as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at gcc-xml ( http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html ), which reuses the gcc frontend to produce an xml description of the source.

Another option is to use the edg frontend ( http://www.edg.com/index.php?location=c_frontend ), but is is not open source, and far from cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php?title=Main_Page) is an option for you? I do not know exactly what result you want. cppcheck is not a pure syntax check. And if cppcheck is fast enougth.