# Is there a gcc options to suppress code generation, but instantiate templates?

Tags: c++, gcc, code-generation

I am trying to use gcc to essentially just check if a C++ program validly compiles without paying the cost of code generation.  There is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577402/g-clang-ultra-fast-parse-but-not-compile-mode) which suggests the -fsyntax-only flag.

This is very close to what I want, but unfortunately, apparently this will not instantiate templates which makes it unsuitable for my purposes.

Is there a way to convince gcc to go further, including all actions up to the actual code generation?

Comment: How would it guess arguments for template parameters, should it try to instantiate templates with all possible parameter types and values combinations?

Comment: I think you are looking for `-S`.  (`-E` preprocess only, `-S` preprocess & compile, `-c` preprocess compile assemble.)

Comment: @273K My understanding, which could be very wrong, is that if it hits a piece of code that needs to instantiate a template it verifies an instantiation could be performed, but does not perform the actual instantiation.